# If someone switches to their family's shared iCloud storage, can they choose to switch back to an individual plan without leaving the Family?

Tags: icloud, storage, family-sharing

I have Family Sharing with 3 other family members through my iCloud+ account (2GB).  Right now, we are not sharing storage, and each of the other family members has either a 200GB or 50GB individual plan.

From Apple's Support pages, I understand that if I go to my Account Storage and select "Share With Family," each person will have the option to join the shared storage plan or keep their current individual plan.

What is **not** clear is whether a family member can later choose to switch back to an individual storage plan without leaving the family group (i.e., going back to the way things were after I started sharing my storage but before they chose to leave their individual plan and use the shared storage).  They should still have Family Sharing for other items (purchases, location sharing, and non-storage subscriptions) -- they just want to opt out of the shared storage plan after they opted in.

Has anyone experienced this or does anyone know that the option exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once someone chooses an iCloud+ shared plan, the original plan can't be access anymore and a refund will be issued for the unused portion.

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208147):

> If a family member is already paying for their own iCloud+ plan, they can choose to switch to your plan or keep their own and still remain part of the family. **When they switch to the shared family plan, they get a refund for the remainder of their personal plan. They can't keep their current plan and use the shared family plan at the same time.**

<sup>Emphasis Mine</sup>

You'll be able to create a new storage plan once you leave, but you can't switch back and forth.  It's best to decide what has the best long-term benefits for you and stick with that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand that they can't have both an individual plan and a shared plan.  My real concern is if the day comes when we're using too much storage as a family.  Can one  member then decide to go back to an individual plan and get their own 2TB plan while still remaining in the general Family Sharing group (NOT sharing storage)?  It sounds like you're saying they can.

Comment: They can leave at any time, it's just that the plan they once had prior to joining the Family Plan will no longer exist so the user will need to get a new plan at the pricing published at that moment.